# Fill table with known row's and column's sums

Tags: algorithm

I know the values of sums in rows and columns in a matrix. The matrix is small (max 10x10) and values are in range from 0 to 99.

Is it possible to generate any matrix from this data? I am not interested in all possible combinations. Just one would be fine.

Ex.

```
Task
              sum in columns     2   5   2
sum in rows    
     7                           ?   ?   ?
     0                           ?   ?   ?
     2                           ?   ?   ?

Answer

2   4   1
0   0   0
0   1   1
```

Comment: You might also find these articles of interest: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/tags/graph+colouring/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int n, m;
int rows[n], cols[m];
int answer[n][m];

while (true) {
    boolean found = false;
    int row = -1, col = -1;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
            if (rows[i] > 0 && cols[j] > 0 && (found == false || Math.min(rows[i], cols[j]) > Math.min(rows[row], cols[col])) {
                found = true;
                row = i;
                col = j;
            }
    if (!found)
        break;
    answer[row][col]++;
    rows[row]--;
    cols[col]--;
}
```

How it works: every time we try to use col and row with most left cells.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it is possible, because there is more than one answer.  For example,

```
0 5 2
0 0 0
2 0 0
```

yields the same row and column sums as the matrix you gave.

Comment: I know. I need any answer. Edited question to clear this fact.

Answer (score 1):

If an answer exists this code will find one:

```
int n, m;
int rows[n], cols[m];
int answer[n][m];

int n, m;
int rows[n], cols[m];
int answer[n][m];

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    int need = rows[i];
    for (int j = 0; need > 0 && j < m; j++) {
        int add = need;
        if (add > cols[j])
            add = cols[j];
        if (add > 99)
            add = 99;
        answer[i][j] = add;
        need -= add;
        cols[j] -= add;
    }
}
```

Comment: How does this code work?  And why does it work?  Can you elaborate on this?

Comment: It's greedy algorithm. Each time we fill one row. To fill the row we try all cells from left to right and put numbers in every cell in the way the number not more than 99 and left cells in the col. But i've understood it's wrong. Wait a sec, i'll post correct solution:)

Comment: It works for me. =) Why do you think that this code is incorrect?

Comment: for example: rows { 1, 1, 1, 1, 100 }, cols { 1, 1, 1, 1, 100}.